# Getting the most present class by group in SAS

Tags: group-by, count, sas

I have a dataset in SAS, let say:
ID, Class, Goup

There is 4 values for group : {1,2,3,4} and an undetermined number of class {Class1, ... , Class n }.

What is the quickest way to find the most present class for each group?

I can see two options, using a `Proc freq` or using something like

```
proq sql; 
Select count(*)
From Have
group by group, class;
```

And after taking the max of each group. But i'm not sure how to finsih..

### EDIT

I said the quickest, but it's more about effectiveness , i'm working on a big table 10 Million lines and i'm runnig it really often

Answer (score 2):

The following step by step approach is one method:

```
data have;
   input group :      8.
         class : $char8.
   ;

   datalines;
1 class1
1 class1
1 class2
1 class3
2 class2
2 class2
2 class2
2 class3
3 class1
3 class2
3 class3
3 class3
;

/* get frequencies */
proc freq data = have noprint;
   tables group*class / out=tmp_freq;
run;

proc sort data = tmp_freq;
   by group count;
run;

data want;
   set tmp_freq;
   by group count;

   if last.group;
run;
```

And the result is

```
Group     Class   Count    Percent
    1    class1       2       16.6
    2    class2       3         25
    3    class3       2       16.6
```

**Edit in response to the question in the comments:**

> On the final table, Percentage are from the whole data, do you think
>   we can have it per class ?

```
data want2(keep = group class max_count percent_for_group);
   /* process data by group */
   do until(last.group);
      set tmp_freq;
      by group;

      if count gt max_count then
         max_count = count;

      sum_count = sum(sum_count,count);
   end;

   percent_for_group = max_count * 100 / sum_count;
run;
```

Comment: On the final table, Percentage are from  the whole data, do you think we can have it per class ?

Comment: Do you mean you want the percentage of the most occurring class within each _group_? So based on the example data they would be (1) 50%, (2), 75% and (3) 50%. Please clarify.